# How to append links to ul in a loop using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of users which I'd like to add to a `ul` list . The code works fine when I add users to the list as `li` elements:

```
users = ['Bob','Mary', 'Mike']
var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
users.forEach(function (user) {
 ul.append($('<li><strong><strong></li>').text(user));
});
$('#users').html(ul);
```

But what I want is to add users as hyperlinked texts so that thay can be clicked, so for example I'd like `Bob` to be rendred as:

```
<li><strong><a href='#' id="Bob">Bob</a><strong></li>
```

But whatever I tried I could not append the `a` elements to `ul` as above. Appreciate your help.

Comment: What have you tried? You simply need to concatenate the names in to the `a` elements of the HTML string.

Comment: Yeah seems pretty basic, especially seeing what you've done so far. But I see no attempt at what you're actually asking for.

Comment: I tried things like `ul.append($('<li><strong><a href="#"><a><strong></li>').text(user))` But the `a` tag is not rendred. Admittedly I'm a noob in jQuery.

Comment: `ul.append('<li><strong><a href="#">'+user+'<a><strong></li>')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just concatenate using the `+` operator:

```js
users = ['Bob','Mary', 'Mike']
var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
users.forEach(function (user) {
  ul.append($('<li><strong><a href="#" id="' + user + '">' + user + '</a></strong></li>'));
});
$('#users').html(ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="users"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good example to start using [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), these are strings, you can easily add variables to:

```js
users = ['Bob','Mary', 'Mike']
var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
users.forEach(function (user) {
  ul.append($(`<li><strong><a href="#" id="${user}">${user}</a></strong></li>`));
});
$('#users').html(ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="users"></div>
```

Comment: Ah! beat me to it :)

Comment: What about cross-browser compatibility issues with this approach?

Comment: Works in everything but IE